# extract values from srting seperated by | in php

Tags: php, string

How to extract values from string seperated by |

here is my string

```
 $var='foo=1478|boo=7854|bar=74125|aaa=74125|bbb=470|ccc=74125|ddd=1200|';
```

i need to store

```
$foo=1478
$boo=7854
$ccc=74125
```

Comment: using the explode function twice, What is the logic of storing??? First two is understandable but what about the last one?? `$c`?

Comment: It looks like you could start with `explode('|', $var);` ... But you must show more research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course every body would suggest the `explode` route:

```
$var = 'foo=1478|boo=7854|bar=74125|aaa=74125|bbb=470|ccc=74125|ddd=1200|';
foreach(array_filter(explode('|', $var)) as $e){
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $e);
    ${$key} = $value;
}
```

Also, another would be to convert pipes to ampersand, so that it can be interpreted with `parse_str`:

```
parse_str(str_replace('|', '&', $var), $data);
extract($data);
echo $foo;
```

Both would produce the same. I'd stay away with variable variables though, it choose to go with arrays.

Comment: I also did something like to the first one.

Comment: @RivnatNasah another variant would be to use regex `preg_split('/\|+/', $var)`

Comment: That's awesome, I love regex but can't do.

Answer (score 0):

Explode the string by `|` and you will get the different value as array which is separated by `|`. Now add the `$` before each value and echo them to see what you want.

```
$var = 'foo=1478|boo=7854|bar=74125|aaa=74125|bbb=470|ccc=74125|ddd=1200|';
$arr = explode("|", $var);
$arr = array_filter($arr);
foreach($arr as $val){
    echo "$".$val."<br/>";
}
```

You will get:

```
$foo=1478
$boo=7854
$bar=74125
$aaa=74125
$bbb=470
$ccc=74125
$ddd=1200
```

OR if you want to store them in the `$foo` variable and show only the value then do this:

```
$var = 'foo=1478|boo=7854|bar=74125|aaa=74125|bbb=470|ccc=74125|ddd=1200|';
$arr = explode("|", $var);
$arr = array_filter($arr);
foreach($arr as $val){
    $sub = explode("=", $val);
    $$sub[0] = $sub[1];
}

echo $foo; //1478
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode` function which can break your string.

```
$array = explode("|", $var);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP variable variable concept to achieve your objective:

**Try this:**

```
<?php
$var='foo=1478|boo=7854|bar=74125|aaa=74125|bbb=470|ccc=74125|ddd=1200|';
$vars=explode("|",$var);
foreach($vars as $key=>$value){
    if(!empty($value)){
        $varcol=explode("=",$value);
        $varname=$varcol[0];
        $varvalue=$varcol[1];
        $$varname=$varvalue;       //In this line we use $$ i.e. variable variable concept
    }
}
echo $foo;
```

I hope this works for you....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for `|` with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove blank elements from array, and pass the result to [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with a reference array.

Inside callback you need to [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) again for `=` and store that in ref array.

there after use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to create variables.

```
$var='foo=1478|boo=7854|bar=74125|aaa=74125|bbb=470|ccc=74125|ddd=1200|';
$result = array();
$x = array_map(function($arr) use(&$result) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $arr);
    $result[$key] = $value;
    return [$key => $value];
}, array_filter(explode('|', $var)));
extract($result);
```